# How do I reduce the X axis on a Google Chart?

Tags: google-api, google-visualization

I'm doing a bar chart with google, and my results [look like this (link)](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bhg&chbh=5&chs=600x500&chxt=x,y&chco=CCFFCC|CCFF99&chd=t:1,5,0,2,6,1,4,1,1,1,1,3,2,1,4,1,4,1,1,1,2,7,4,2,5,2,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,3&chxl=1%3a|BangKapi|BangKhae|BangKhoLaem|BangKhunThian|BangPhlat|BangRak|BangkokNoi|BangkokYai|Chatuchak|ChomThong|DinDaeng|Dusit|HuaiKhwang|KhanNaYao|KhlongSamWa|KhlongSan|LatKrabang|LatPhrao|MinBuri|NongChok|NongKhaem|PathumWan|PhasiCharoen|PhayaThai|PhraNakhon|PomPrapSattruPhai|Prawet|Ratchathewi|SaiMai|SuanLuang|TalingChan|ThawiWatthana|ThonBuri|WangThonglang|YanNawa).

If you see that the graph is not beautiful enough. What is the parameter that can reduce the value on the x axis.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

try [this one](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bhg&chbh=5&chs=600x500&chxt=x,y&chco=CCFFCC|CCFF99&chds=0,10&chd=t:1,5,0,2,6,1,4,1,1,1,1,3,2,1,4,1,4,1,1,1,2,7,4,2,5,2,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,3&chxl=1%3a|BangKapi|BangKhae|BangKhoLaem|BangKhunThian|BangPhlat|BangRak|BangkokNoi|BangkokYai|Chatuchak|ChomThong|DinDaeng|Dusit|HuaiKhwang|KhanNaYao|KhlongSamWa|KhlongSan|LatKrabang|LatPhrao|MinBuri|NongChok|NongKhaem|PathumWan|PhasiCharoen|PhayaThai|PhraNakhon|PomPrapSattruPhai|Prawet|Ratchathewi|SaiMai|SuanLuang|TalingChan|ThawiWatthana|ThonBuri|WangThonglang|YanNawa)

I just added chds=0,10 to scale it properly.  That basically sets the data range to 0 min, 10 max.

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at this [link](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/data_formats.html#scaled_values) from google regarding Data Scaling. I am not sure of your data set format so the actual answer to your problem will depend on that.

i.e. - I added "&chds=0,10" after your "chd=" statment and got a better looking chart. [Example](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bhg&chbh=5&chs=600x500&chxt=x,y&chco=CCFFCC|CCFF99&chd=t:1,5,0,2,6,1,4,1,1,1,1,3,2,1,4,1,4,1,1,1,2,7,4,2,5,2,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,3&chds=0,10&chxl=1%3a|BangKapi|BangKhae|BangKhoLaem|BangKhunThian|BangPhlat|BangRak|BangkokNoi|BangkokYai|Chatuchak|ChomThong|DinDaeng|Dusit|HuaiKhwang|KhanNaYao|KhlongSamWa|KhlongSan|LatKrabang|LatPhrao|MinBuri|NongChok|NongKhaem|PathumWan|PhasiCharoen|PhayaThai|PhraNakhon|PomPrapSattruPhai|Prawet|Ratchathewi|SaiMai|SuanLuang|TalingChan|ThawiWatthana|ThonBuri|WangThonglang|YanNawa).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the help file [here](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/making_charts.html#making_a_chart).

> Decide whether your data must be scaled to fit your chart. Different formats support different ranges of values. You might want to scale your data so that it spans the full range of values allowed by your format, to make differences more obvious. You can do this either by scaling your data to fit within the data format that you use, or you can use text formatting with custom scaling.